# react-string-replace not working with regex

Tags: reactjs, string, replace

I was trying to use the library **react-string-replace** as in React we have a limited way of using string replace method.

I was using trying to match some sub-string using regex as mentioned below as shown in the documentation but I am not able to get the desired result. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
const str = 'Hey this a sample string.'
const result = reactStringReplace(str, '/(sample)/g', match => <span style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>{match}</span>)
```

The above code does not changes the style of the string. but when I remove the regex and place a simple string, It works.

```
const str = 'Hey this a sample string.'
const result = reactStringReplace(str, 'sample', match => <span style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>{match}</span>)
```

I want to make this work using regex as there are couple of other string on which I wanna apply the same style. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the single quotes `''` from **sample** regex.

**Edit:** you'll need to add a `key` prop in the returned JSX otherwise you will get a `Warning` in your log: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

**Syntax should look like:**

```js
const str = 'Hey this a sample string.'
const result = reactStringReplace(str, /(sample)/g, (match, i) => <span key={i} style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>{match}</span>)
```

[image: Edit little-snow-nn20m]

---

Actually you don't need a library to do this, you can do it in React way using [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

```js
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("")

  const handleClick = () => {
    const str = "Hey this a sample string."
    // You'll need to use regular inline CSS
    const result = str.replace(
      "sample",
      '<span style="color:red">sample</span>'
    )

    setText(result)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Change text style</button>
      <br />
      <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> , document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Learn more about [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why you need a special package to do this, doesn't this work?

```
const str = 'Hey this a sample string.'
const patt = /(sample)/g
match = str.match(new RegExp(patt))

return <span style={{fontStyle: 'italic'}}>{match}</span>
```